# Increasing width of html display by having columns appear multiple times

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I have a webpage made using Flask and it displays a table. I am trying to increase the width of the display by simply having columns appear multiple times. This might be hard to explain so below is an illustration:

I have:

Col1 Col2

data data

data data

data data

data data

I want:

Col Col2  Col1 Col2

data data data data

data data data data

My HTML code is as follows (myDisplay is just the table info from Python):

```
<div class="display">          
        {{myDisplay | safe}}      
</div>
```

And CSS is:

```
.display{
max-height: 500px;
}
```

What I am going for is to limit the height of my div to 500px so that my table would be forced to expand horizontally after it reaches that 500px vertically.

Comment: without any code of your table, how it increases , and where new cells are supposed to show, it's gonna be difficult for you to get an answer. Clarify .

Comment: Hi I added code for clarification. Hopefully it is helpful. My own illustration above is where the new cells are supposed to show.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need an HTML table?

For an HTML example, check out table, th, td, and tr tags to make a table.
You can also style a table with CSS. I added style="width:20%" here to increase column width. You can customize the table any way that you want but, this would require additional CSS styling.

If you have to pass inputs in multiple times for some reason "using flask or whatever you are using for server-side" you would specify that in additional th and td tags.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>The table element</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th style="width:20%">Month</th>
    <th style="width:30%">Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/34enbqka/

For Flask here is an example from flask-table on how you would create a table similar to above using the flask_table module.

```
from flask_table import Table, Col


class ItemTable(Table):
    name = Col('Name')
    description = Col('Description')

class Item(object):
    def __init__(self, name, description):
        self.name = name
        self.description = description

items = [Item('Name1', 'Description1'),
         Item('Name2', 'Description2'),
         Item('Name3', 'Description3')]
# Or, equivalently, some dicts
items = [dict(name='Name1', description='Description1'),
         dict(name='Name2', description='Description2'),
         dict(name='Name3', description='Description3')]


items = ItemModel.query.all()


table = ItemTable(items)


print(table.__html__())
```

Result

```
<table>
<thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Description</th></tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>Name1</td><td>Description1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Name2</td><td>Description2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Name3</td><td>Description3</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```